# Lack of support of hierarchical roles and groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the trinity of authorization systems of (resource, user, permission), GCP supports "resource grouping" in the form of **hierarchical** "organization-folder-project". And users can be in "groups", permissions can be grouped into "roles". But I can't find support of hierarchy in the latter two. Specifically there is no group of groups, nor roles of roles in GCP. It seems that lack of such hierarchies makes close modeling of business units and roles, and management at scale, difficult in GCP.

It looks like AWS also doesn't support hierarchy in one or two of the user/permission groupings either. In comparison, Oracle supports grouping hierarchy in all three.

I am wondering if anyone can confirm the above statement regarding the GCP support, and shed more lights on any high level considerations, and/or roadmaps of future support, and/or possible workarounds, on GCP.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why can't you add groups in group?

Answer (score 1):

In the organizational level you can create a nested group as described from GSuite perspective in this [doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167100?hl=en),in IAM & admin is possible as well, about the role's permissions, if you grant them into a nested Group those will be inherited as described in previous [doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167100?hl=en)

#### Update

In IAM the higher basic roles (owner) includes the permissions of a lower level role (Editor), and the Editor role includes the permissions in the Viewer role.

[image]

As you can see there's a hierarchy that works acquiring the lower level role permissions. if this structure does not fulfills your Organization requirements you can choose the [Predefined](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles) roles which often use permission inheritance between roles.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding "role hierarchy", I did not mean the hierarchy of role *application* that can be through the hierarchal groups.  But I meant the hierarchy of role *definition* so that high level roles can be defined on top of lower level ones.  This would be useful if the role system is very complex and involved.

Comment: @YanZjou Thanks for your clarification, I've updated my answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM) lets administrators authorize who can take action on specific resources, giving you full control and visibility to manage Google Cloud resources centrally. For enterprises with complex organizational structures, hundreds of workgroups, and many projects, Cloud IAM provides a unified view into security policy across your entire organization, with built-in auditing to ease compliance processes. You can read thru this links for more information. [1](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#how_cloud_iam_works)

This link describes the IAM roles that you can grant to identities to access Google Cloud resources. [2](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)